# The "movie jail": is that idiomatic and how to express this differently?

Tags: expressions, synonyms, phrase-choice

A French article claimed the term "*movie jail*" could not be translated. I found the following sort of sarcastic explanation about the expression on some random [website](http://www.joblo.com/tag/movie-jail/) as I can't find it in *Collins/Dictionary.com/TFD*:

> This is Movie Jail, a unique maximum security prison that houses some
>   of the worst writers, directors, actors and producers from Hollywood
>   and beyond. Their crimes? The offenses vary from convict to convict
>   but most of these inmates have contributed negatively to the film
>   world to some capacity* and his or her misdeeds have covered a long
>   enough period of time that the authorities had to intervene.

I noted the capital letters "*Movie Jail*"; is that something coined or a magazine trademark of any kind, or just literal English used figuratively i.e. "*the jail of the movie industry*". Is that mainly *AmE*? What is another idiomatic way of expressing the *movie jail* idea which showcases further the impact on the artist without resorting to the penitentiary system metaphor?

Comment: Movie Jail is not an every day term.  From the above context, I understand this term, in a very sarcastic sense, as a way to make fun of people who have made poor or damaging contributions to the movie industry as a whole.  These people, for the good of everyone else, must be pulled from society so that they cannot continue to damage people with their awful films.  Another metaphor - would be perhaps the Survivor series trope of "voting them off the island."  Or perhaps taking away their pens before they accidently stab themselves with them (like young children with sharp objects.)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Thank you! That would make an interesting answer as you also provide two other metaphors, the last one being popular culture neutral so to speak, which I find quite interesting.

Comment: Then answer it becomes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Movie Jail is not an every day term. From the above context, I understand this term, in a very sarcastic sense, as a way to make fun of people who have made poor or damaging contributions to the movie industry as a whole. These people, for the good of everyone else, must be pulled from society so that they cannot continue to damage people with their awful films. Another metaphor - would be perhaps the Survivor series trope of "voting them off the island." Or perhaps taking away their pens before they accidently stab themselves with them (like young children with sharp objects.)

Comment: _"Movie hall of shame"_ and _"movie penalty box"_ would also have similar meanings.